# Fail an INSERT if value column does not exist in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that would allow you to insert a new Room in a Building, but fail if that building ID does not exist

```sql
INSERT INTO room (
    building_id, room_name
) VALUES (
    $1, 
    CONCAT('Room ', (SELECT count(1) +1 FROM room WHERE building_id = $1))
)
RETURNING building_id, id, room_name, version
```

Currently you can do the insert with any random building id and it would end up as garbage data in the room table and lots of `Room 1` entries with non-existing building ids.

Trying something like this (obviously inside a transaction) works, but what happens if the building gets deleted just after the SELECT runs before the INSERT happens?

```sql
INSERT INTO room (
    building_id, 
    room_name
) 
SELECT 
    $1, 
    CONCAT(
        'Room ',
        (SELECT count(1) + 1
        FROM room AS r 
        WHERE r.building_id = $1)
    )
FROM building AS b
WHERE b.id = $1
RETURNING building_id, id, room_name, version
```

It's very unlikely though, but I'm still curious if it can be avoided.

Can this query be improved to completely avoid such concurrency issues or is there a way to use foreign keys to enforce the room insert to always have a valid building_id when the transaction commits or maybe some other novel solution?

Comment: Usually you would have a foreign key constraint pointing to the table with all buildings. That would prevent your current situation

Comment: What you describe is wanting  *referential integrity* which is  **exactly** what creating a [Foreign Key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-fk.html) provides. Further, you do not need the select of the building in your query.

Comment: Referential integrity is indeed what I was looking for, I was using it everywere already except for literally this one case. *facepalm* for missing the obvious.
`building_id  uuid REFERENCES building (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,`
Will accept that as a correct answer; thanks for finding my bug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple constraint would stop a room from being inserted if the building did not exists.

Try adding a constraint - something like this would give you something to test with.

```
CREATE TABLE building(
    id int UNIQUE, 
    name varchar(15)
);

CREATE TABLE room(
    id int UNIQUE, 
    building_id int, 
    name varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT foreign_key_room_building
        FOREIGN KEY(building_id) 
        REFERENCES building(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT unique_id_building_id
        UNIQUE (id, building_id)    
);

INSERT INTO building
    (id, name)
VALUES
    (1, 'orange building'),
    (2, 'red building')
;
     
INSERT INTO room
    (id, building_id, name)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'front room'),
    (2, 1, 'back room')
;
```

then the following code will fail.

```
INSERT INTO room
    (id, building_id, name)
VALUES
    (3, 3, 'front room')
;
```

which results with the error

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "room" violates foreign key constraint "foreign_key_room_building" Detail: Key (building_id)=(3) is not present in table "building".
```

Here is a SQLFiddle link to play with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/babbf7/1